# ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: python, import

I downloaded a Python wrapper called rawpy recently using easy_install (pip install did not work). When I imported it and attempted to run code, this error appeared: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."

Could anyone offer a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at similar questions on SO and found that a common theme was that they had incorrect versions of whatever they were working with. I decided to switch to Python 3.5.3 over 2.7; this fixed the problem, but a new error "ImportError: No module named 'rawpy'" appeared. This is because the module is now in the incorrect directory. I was able to fix this by uninstalling and reinstalling the module using pip.